# How to change rootElement when there is interaction of two apps

Tags: protractor

I've a use case where it is to be automate  two different apps interaction in a jasmine suite.
So two different apps  there would be different rootElement for two apps.
How should we manage this rootElement. I've tried one setting in config.js and i can interact with first app url and then chnaged browser.rootEl = '[ng-app="muiApp"]';to interact second  app but it is not working .

In a suite multipe specs involving interactions between the two apps

Getting error:

```
Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
```

Comment: What protractor version are you using?

Comment: Interesting. Could you show the relevant code where you switch from one app to another? Thanks.

Comment: browser.rootEl = '[ng-app="muiApp"]';

Comment: In the jasmine spec i have added this statement, infact i tried without changing rootEl , i am getting same results

Comment: Any other info need it @alecxe

Comment: Please edit the question and add the complete test spec involving interactions between the two apps. Thanks.

Comment: If i separate in two suites its working , but my requirement is specs in a suite,Thanks

Comment: Can we change rootElement through jasmine spec

Comment: Please share some example code, ideally a small reproducible case. What you want is an uncommon use case but you may be able to switch the root element and then call [`browser.waitForAngular`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/b110ed92442eb8b14768c512a890bb3ceb0e4973/lib/protractor.js#L348) to re-synchronize.

Comment: can we switch root element using the statment in  
browser.rootEl = '' in specs

Comment: @NickTomlin I can see a comment from your devs in protractor issue page that we should change rootEl in the spec, is rootEl should be static

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to change the root element, you have to change it within the context of the control flow:

```
app1.doThings();
browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
    browser.rootEl = 'app2';
)};
switchToApp2();
app2.doThings();

browser.controlFlow().execute(function() {
    browser.rootEl = 'app1';
)};
switchToApp1();
app1.doThings();
```